# Installing Apache Flex 4.9 inside FlashBuilder 4.7

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder

It is great that Apache Flex has produced the new Flex 4.9.0, but I have been unable to figure out how to install this inside Flash Builder 4.7.  It seems that Flex 4.9.0 is incomplete because of licensing, and that it needs to be built.  Are there instructions anywhere?

Or, if it is possible to install Air 3.5 (or 3.4) inside the Flex 4.6 sdk, that would also be a good solution as well.

It seems that Flash Builder 4.7 now requires Air 3.4 in order to do debugging on the device over USB, but it comes with Air 3.1 inside Flex 4.6.

Comment: The Apache Flex 4.9 Installer is currently in an RC stage. You should be able to find more information on the Apache Flex dev lists.  I wouldn't call Apache Flex incomplete, however it does contain requirements on some non-open source solutions which Apache cannot distribute, but Adobe could.  At the time of this writing; Apache is in the process of moving the Flex domains / mailing lists from the incubator to formal top level projects; so there may be some issues during that transition.  I expect them to be resolved quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the new Apache Flex installer for version 4.9

http://flex.apache.org/installer.html

Answer (score 5):

Apache Flex has just released a new installer for 4.9 that will package up the official Apache Flex 4.9 binary distribution and add to it all the required 3rd party software so that it works correctly with Flash Builder 4.6 and 4.7. It will install AIR 3.4 as part of that process.

As marcus pointed out above the installer can be found at.
http://flex.apache.org/installer.html

At the accept license page be sure to tick all of the red boxes so you can progress.

I was the release manager for Apache flex 4.9 so happy to answer any questions about it.

Answer (score 2):

Installing air is extremely easy - you just have to `ctrl+c` it and `ctrl+v` into flex sdk folder.

Regarding new Apache Flex - you can use their installer for version `4.8`, however, it seems that now it is broken, so you can either wait for it to be fixed and configured for version `4.9` or try do follow those instructions:
http://lucamezzalira.com/2012/07/24/how-to-install-flex-4-8-0-sdk-in-flash-builder/

Comment: Thanks very much for the link.  In addition to the instructions, I also found the following post on that page from Carol Frampton of the Flex team,: "Alternatively, on Mac OSX, you can download and unzip the binaries into a directory.

cd apache-flex-sdk-4.8.0-incubating-bin/ide/flashbuilder
./makeApacheFlexForFlashBuilder.sh /Applications/Adobe\ Flash\ Builder\ 4.5/sdks/4.8.0

The script will pull together all the parts you need and copy the sdk to the specified directory."

Comment: The comment about installing air seems incomplete.  There must be some Flash Builder property settings needed to get it to recognize the new air runtime.

Comment: You may also need to edit flex-config.xml and air-config.xml files. You are better off using the installer or the scripts in the ide directory if you need different version of AIR.